# how to use Rxjava2 Maybe to implement Repository Pattern

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am trying to use Rxjava2 to implement the repository pattern, I have read this article [RxJava 2 — Single.concat sample for Repository Pattern](https://android.jlelse.eu/rxjava-2-single-concat-sample-for-repository-pattern-1873c456227a)

It seems that the workaround is to create a Container Class to help check if the object is null, which means a bit more code structure changes.

It also recommend to use Maybe, but no any example. I tried with

```
protected Maybe<Foo> loadDataFromCache() {
    return Maybe.just(cacheDataHelper.getFoo());
}
```

But I still receive NullPointerException when there is no cached data

So can anyone give me an example of how to use Rxjava2 Maybe to implement Repository Pattern please?

Comment: RxJava2 enforces non-null. Why not use an `Optional` e.g. `Optional.ofNullable(cacheDataHelper.getFoo())` then you can use `ifPresent` operator, what's the benefit of using RxJava if all it does is use `just` operator?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer which may be not perfectly elegant, but it works.
Just use Maybe.empty()

An example code would be:

```
protected Maybe<Foo> getDataFromCache() {
    Foo foo = localDataHelper.getFoo();
    return foo != null ? Maybe.just(foo) : Maybe.empty();
}

public Single<Foo> loadDataFromMultipleRepos (int teamId) {
    Maybe<Foo> apiCallObservable = getDataFromCache().toMaybe();
    Maybe<Foo> cacheObservable = loadDataFromCache();

    return Maybe.concat(cacheObservable, apiCallObservable)
            .toSingle();
}
```

But I am still looking for a more elegant rx way to implement getDataFromCache() method. Thanks